# find which app/package is using consuming wifi data via adb android

Tags: android, adb

I just purchased jiofi wifi. when I connect my Vivo z1pro to wifi. it consumes at least 1MB/S. even it consumed 2.6 GB a day. So I checked in data usages in settings and found that google app is using that data. so I disabled google app. 
Next day again my phone is consuming wifi at the same speed. again I checked my wifi data where total consumption was 1.2 GB but when I count all listed app it's less than 100 mb.
So, I don't know which app is using my wifi data.
If it could be solved, by anyone.

Is there any way to find which app or package is using my wifi data via adb.
sorry for bad English in advance.